# How to i add CRON Job in Vesta CP Pannel What is Command

Tags: php, cron

How can i add my file of php and txt in cron job of 10 mint for example
my url is : `http://example.com/xx/file.php` 
and `http://example.com/xx/file.txt`
and I'm try this command wget `http://example.com/xx/file.php` 
when i add this command panel email me in spam of error.

[image: Here is Screen Shoot of my Vestacp Pannel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
wget -q -O - "http://example.com/xx/file.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

[image]

Comment: does it work for `https`? how to ignore SSL issue in this command?

Comment: wget  --no-check-certificate "https: